# Direction - Adding holes to a mesh

Tags: mesh, geometry

This is not a question of "How do I add holes is a mesh", rather a question of direction.
I have a mesh that I need to add a hole/slot to for a game. This slot will be filled by some item during the duration of the game.

The only solution I've thought of is simply adding geometry to make a hole and snapping the item on that hole in the game, but I was wondering if there's a different/potentially better way of doing it, and unfortunately it's not something I can easily look up on Google.

What things could I look up?

Comment: Without any images showing what you want to do it's impossible to say. Even a sketch showing what you want might be useful.

Comment: Typically, for a fit, you would use one object to manufacture the other, by Boolean or borrowing geometry, in the same place, and setting the rest pose / object-origin-alignment to the  settled, fitting position. Please give us a concrete  example, this is not clear, as it stands.